# Using VB.net to alter Stored Parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am having an issue modifying a stored procedure variable with VB.net. I have found many posts on the topic that made it seem like a simple `.AddWithValue`  solution but I keep ending up with a the following exception:

> The IListSource does not contain any data sources.

The stored procedure is a Dynamic Pivot table that works great with a static value for `@dcs`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dcspull]
as
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @dcs AS INT



select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FirstName) 
               FROM[Training Data]
               WHERE DataCenterID = @dcs 
               GROUP by FirstName
               ORDER by FirstName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT  ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(FirstName)+''''') 
                AS '+QUOTENAME(+FirstName)
                FROM [Training Data]
                WHERE DataCenterID = @dcs
                GROUP by FirstName
                ORDER by FirstName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Topic, ' + @colsNull + ' 
                 FROM
                 (SELECT FirstName, Topic, Level
                 FROM [Training Data]) x
                 PIVOT
                    (MAX(Level)
                    FOR FirstName IN (' + @cols + ')) p'

execute(@query)
```

The only value I am trying to change via VB.Net is `@dcs`. When `@dcs` is set statically the Gridview populates as expected, but as soon as I try to pass a value to the parameter it breaks.

```
Dim SQLCon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("tCString").ToString
Dim DBConnSQL As New SqlConnection(SQLCon)
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
DBConnSQL.Open()
Dim dbcheckone As New SqlCommand("dcspull", DBConnSQL)
dbcheckone.parameters.addwithvalue("@dcs", Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList1.Text))
da.SelectCommand = dbcheckone
da.Fill(ds)
GridView1.DataSource = ds
GridView1.DataBind()
```

I am fairly new to stored procedures and am assuming this is something I just don't understand about the relationship.

Comment: The first problem is that I don't see your SqlCommand being set to a CommandType of Stored Procedure. Secondly I don't the SPROC accepting the @dcs parameter, you do declare it but that is not the same as the SPROC accepting the parameter when it gets invoked

Comment: You also add a parameter in your code but there isn't a parameter in your procedure.

Comment: You might also want to look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Thanks for tips, I didn't realize that the "Declares" were not procedures. as I said, new to stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't see any parameters in your stored procedure. They should come before `AS`.
Sample Create SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2 
    @LastName nvarchar(50), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(50) 
 AS
```

Now, when you add those parameters it should work under these conditions:

1. You need to set command Type

`dbcheckone.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

2. Even though you don't use other parameters during your call, your procedure signature and procedure itself don't match. You can't omit non-optional parameters. So you need to list every parameter

`dbcheckone.parameters.addwithvalue("@cols"...`
`dbcheckone.parameters.addwithvalue("@colsNull"...`
`dbcheckone.parameters.addwithvalue("@query"...`
`dbcheckone.parameters.addwithvalue("@dcs", Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.Text))`

About the last line here - you set it in your code to  `Convert.ToInt64` but your parameter is `int`, therefore it should match `int32`.

Comment: that worked like a charm! I tried the vb.net scripts with everything you listed (other than not realizing that it needed to be int32). the problem was my lack of knowledge about Parameters having to be stated before the AS and not with the other Declares!